# Groovy DSLD doc not showing

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I want to make a custom DSLD to have content assist in eclipse. Eclipse recognizes the DSLD and gives assist, but the documentation is not shown in the editor.

The DSLD:

```
(isThisType()).accept {
    method name: 'search',
               type: 'void',
               params: [:],
               doc: "documentation thats not showing"
}
```

I want to make the assist to a script file with a single line:

```
search()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider two cases.

**First case** You have your script is placed in some package folder but it doesn't specify the package in its code, the doc feature fails. As soon as the package would be specified the doc would come up.

**Second case** The script is placed in src folder (aka default package) or any other folder the doc works.